# Swapping two numbers by reference and using pointers?

Tags: compiler-errors

I tried to make a program of swapping two numbers, but when i run this program its shows error and i am confused how to do it by using pointers and reference.

### A program to swap two numbers by using reference and pointers.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void swap(int &, int &);
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cout<<"Enter the value of a and b:";
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<"Before swapping......";
    cout<<"A=" <<*a;
    cout<<"\nB=" <<*b;
    swap(a,b);
    cout<<"\nAfter swapping......";
    cout<<"\nA="  <<a;
    cout<<"\nB="  <<b;
    return 0;
}
void swap(int & *x, int & *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
}
```

Here i got error.

---

### There are the statements in which i am having errors.

cout<<"A=" <<*a;

---

cout<<"\nB=" <<*b;

---

void swap(int & *x, int & *y)

[image: Here the compiler shows errors]

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: 10 16 E:\Studies\swap using reference.cpp [Error] invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')                          I am using Dev C++

Comment: @IjlalHussain - I think you need to declare a and b as pointers in the main function and temp as a pointer in your swap method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message clearly says in what part of program you are having an error. You are using multiplication (*) in your cout. It should be just like this:

```
cout << "A = " << a;
cout << "\nB = " << b;
```

Also in your swap method, it should be like this:

```
void swap(int x, int y)
{
    int temp;
    temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
}
```